# Last line of text field truncation in jasper

Tags: java, jasper-reports

I have a scenario where i am printing HTML data from Database. I will view the jasper report from Web application through java code. While i am viewing this HTML data 
the last line of that data is not getting printed (mrakup=html and strechwithoverflow=true). Can anyone please suggest what could be reason and solution for this.

As a workaround, i added a break character at end and now data is printed, but it creates a new blank page when we have data fit for one page.

Comment: Did you try to export report as pdf, for example? Is it ok?

Comment: I am trying export report as pdf. I having this issue. I am not trying other formats.